# Add css class to a td tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm trying to make a timetable for a Moodle in form of a Greasemonkey script.

The idea is to highlight the subject for the current hour, but i can't find a working way of doing it.

I'm injecting css into the page, and using jQuery to add the injected css class to the target td.

This is the css code injected into the page header:

```
.current_class {background-color:green};
```

And this is the javascript code used to add the class to the td:

```
var cell = $("#timetable_table").find("tr").eq(current+1).find("td").eq(date.getDay());
```

I know cell is the correct td because i can cell.text("foo") and the correct cell is modified, but when i do:

```
cell.addClass("current_class");
```

the table stays the same.

I don't have to do it that way, i only want to dynamically change the background on a td tag, so i don't mind using other methods.

Thanks.

Comment: could you provide some of your table html?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with your HTML table, CSS and JS too?

Comment: Where do `current` and `date` come from?

Comment: Can you confirm that the class attribute of the element is changed? Your CSS should have the semicolon immediately after green.

Comment: I'm new to this and i'm generating the table dynamically. But i'm going to try ;)

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals after adding the semicolon yes, it's on the class attribute, but the color doesn't change

Comment: Your code runs fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tC8vL/ You need to add more context like is there other classes added to the cells?

Comment: @epascarello i can't post the table unfortunately, but the td with the times get a speciall class "custom_table_hour" for identification purposes.

Comment: So you need to make the rule more specific to override the other class. CSS 101 stuff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I would suggest you change to this:

```
var cell = document.getElementById('timetable_table').rows(current+1).cells(date.getDay());
```

And:

```
cell.className += (cell.className ? " " : "")+"current_class";
```

But that's just for [performance reasons](http://vanilla-js.com/)

The probable cause of the issue is that you have `background-color` being defined elsewhere with greater specificity. Try using this CSS selector:

```css
#timetable_table tr>td.current_class{background-color:green};
```

That should be specific enough to win.

Comment: Could be the problem, becouse as stated before, i'm modifying a page, so might be alredy defined. But i dont understand the selector: it selects td with the class alredy?

Comment: CSS updates in realtime. So if you add a class to a cell in that table, it will match the selector and the new style will be applied.

Comment: so you are telling me to .addClass() and then to use the selector to add the background-color prop?

Answer (score 2):

use className property for change or add class like example:

```
tbody.firstChild.lastChild.className='tr-parent1';
```